# VB.Net DataGridView update query results

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I am currently working in converting an out of date Access application in to a .Net application.

In Access we have a query on a form that contains a list of customers and vehicles where the users can edit the data as required.

I followed the following guide to populate the data grid

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.90).aspx

As you could expect I need to replicate this functionality in .Net, I have been able to populate a DataGridView with the results of a query joining the two tables however I have not been able to work out how to handle the update of the tables through the DataGridView. I understand the as the DataGridView contains the results of a query i need to manually code the UpdateCommand of the DataAdapter and this is where i am stuck.

In Short i need to update two tables though a single data grid view.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add a hidden column(s) with the unique key(s) that join the two tables together and then write two update queries (one for each table) and use the hidden column(s) as the parameters for your `WHERE` clause in each query.